# Parse using beautifulSoup Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('http://arithmetic.zetamac.com/game?key=96823302')
problem = soup.findAll('problem')
print(problem)
```

The `problem` on the webpage was the text, but this does not print.What is the problem here?

Comment: What is the output so far?

Comment: What are you wanting to get?

Comment: Note that, if you want to automate that website, beautifulsoup is the wrong tool

Comment: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` Is this working? It should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

First off you should be using *bs4*, not the no longer maintained *beautifulSoup3*, second *problem* is the *class name* not a *tag*. You need to look for a *span tag* with that class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://arithmetic.zetamac.com/game?key=96823302").content)

problem = soup.find("span",class_="problem")
```

That will give you `<span class="problem"></span>` but as you can see the text is not there because it is added using *Javascript*.

Comment: Would I use single quots (') or double (")?

Comment: So Is it possible to retrive the text as it appears each time somehow?